# How to return value from TimerTask in groovy

Tags: asynchronous, groovy, timer, timertask, completable-future

I'm trying to invoke **getStatus** method for every **3 seconds** and checking am I getting the **Done** status from my database (remove database code for this testing purpose). Once I got the status "**Done**" I'm coming out of while loop and I want to return this status to testMethod. But my code is not returning anything back to CompletableFuture. What I'm doing wrong here - can someone please help me to fix this? My code snippet:

```
CompletableFuture.supplyAsync({ -> getStatus()
        }).thenAccept({ status -> testMethod(status) })

def getStatus() {
        def response
        Timer timer = new Timer()
        TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask(){
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        while(true) {
                            // Doing some DB operation to check the work status is changing to Done and assigning to response
                            response = "Done"
                            if (response == "Done") {
                                timer.cancel()
                                break;
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
        timer.schedule(timerTask, 3000)
        return response
    }


def testMethod(status) {
        System.out.println("testMethod... " +status)
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are scheduling the timer task and then immediately return the current value of response from getStatus().  3 seconds later or so that task sets the local variable to "Done" but nobody outside the task is looking at that now.

A better approach might be for getStatus itself to return a CompletableFuture.  Which the task can populate when it's done.

So something like this:

```
getStatus().thenAccept({ status -> testMethod(status) })

def getStatus() {
   def future = new CompletableFuture<String>()
   Timer timer = new Timer()
   TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask(){
      @Override
      public void run() {
         while(true) {
            // Doing some DB operation to check the work status is changing to Done and assigning to response
            def response = "Done"
            if (response == "Done") {
               timer.cancel()
               future.complete(response)
               break;
            }

         }
      }
   }
   timer.schedule(timerTask, 3000)
   return future
}


def testMethod(status) {
   System.out.println("testMethod... " +status)
}
```

EDIT - to add on some kind of timeout you might instead use a ScheduledExecutorService like so:

```
import java.util.concurrent.*


ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(2)

getStatus(executor).thenAccept({ status -> testMethod(status) })


def getStatus(executor) {
   def future = new CompletableFuture<String>()

   def count = 0

   def task

   def exec = {
      println("Running : $count")
      // Doing some DB operation to check the work status is changing to Done and assigning to response
      def response = "NotDone"
      if (response == "Done") {
         future.complete(response)
         task.cancel()
      }
      else if (++count == 10) {
         future.complete("Failed")
         task.cancel()
      }
   } as Runnable

   task = executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(exec, 3, 3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)

   future
}


def testMethod(status) {
   System.out.println("testMethod... " +status)
}
```

So I just used an iteration count to stop it running more than 10 times but that could be count or time based.  Whatever makes sense for your use case.

Comment: Thanks - it works. Is there any way to add timeout if I'm not getting the response "Done" in 3 minutes - timeout and send "failed" as a response?

Comment: Sure.  There's all sorts of ways you can do that.  But it probably makes more sense to use a ScheduledExecutorService or similar if you want to do anything more complicated.  That then allows you to cancel a task.  You could for instance use scheduledAtFixedRate to run every x seconds until complete or the max time has been reached.  See the edited answer.